# Linq: Using Distinct on calculated result

Tags: linq

I have a query which calculates a range of dates which I want to run a distinct query on to return just Year/Month combinations. I can't work out how best to achieve this.

```
        private IEnumerable<DateTime> MonthsWithItineraryData (int Id) // shipId
    {
        var months = (from i in context.Itineraries
                          join isd in context.ItineraryStartDates on i.Id equals isd.ItineraryId
                          join id in context.ItineraryDay on i.Id equals id.ItineraryId
                          where i.ShipId == Id
                          select  (DateTime)DbFunctions.AddDays(isd.Date, id.Day)
                          );
        return (months);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
return monts.GroupBy(x => new {x.Month, x.Year})
            .Select(x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

or else you can  a custom equality comparer as distinct argument:

```
public class DateTimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime> 
{ 
  public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y) 
  { 
    return x.Year == y.Year && x.Month == y.Month; 
  } 
  public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj) 
  { 
    return obj.Year * 100 + obj.Month; 
  } 
} 

result = months.Distinct(new DateTimeComparer()).ToList();
```